# Replace string in multiple files (same directory) with condition

Tags: centos, string, replace

Example:

File1:

```
Name: abc
Number: 325
Code: 0
```

File2:

```
Name: xyz
Number: 578
Code: 0
```

File3:

```
Name: ttt
Number: 356
Code: 0
```

File4:

```
Name: nnn
Number: 228
Code: 0
```

File5:

```
Name: bnb
Number: 434
Code: 0
```

Question is how to change *Code* to *1* but only if *Number* is *3xx* or *2xx*. So File2 and File5 remain unchanged.

Files have a lot more lines, and there are about 100 files, but this is just simplified example, how to replace one string in file (line x) but only if other string (line y) in that file is corresponding.

Comment: Could you, please, reformat your question ? So far, it suggests that all files contain only 1 line (but I guess this is not true), and this is actually pretty important to give you an answer that works.

Comment: Does the `Code:` line always follow right after the `Number:` line?

Comment: @steeldriver No, Code: line isn't after the Number: line.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job :

```
sed -i 's/^Code: 0$/Code: 1/' $(grep -l '^Number: [23]' File*)
```

- the `sed` part does the actual replacements
- the `grep -l ... File*` part lists all files with name matching 'File*' and having a line starting with either `Number: 2` or `Number: 3`
- the `$(...)` construct surrounding the `grep` command is a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) that will feed files listed by `grep` into `sed`

Comment: That assumes `$IFS` has not been modified and the file names don't contain space, tab newline or wildcard characters though.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU tools:

```
grep -lxZ 'Number: [23]..' ./File* |
  xargs -r0 sed -i 's/^Code: 0$/Code: 1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Number* always precedes *Code*, and *Code* might have any value, then using `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^Number: [23]/{n;s/^Code: .*$/Code 1/}' File*
```

If the content is consistent, so that the line after *Number* is always *Code 0*, that can be simplified to:

```
sed -i '/^Number: [23]/{n;s/0/1/}' File*
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **sed** for this task without creating temporary files because redirecting back to the source would destroy the file's contents.
Instead, use the **ed editor**.
I assume that filenames are in the range [a-zA-Z0-9_-]

```
% cat scr.ed
1,$s/Code: 0/Code: 1/
w
q
% cat scr.sh
#!/bin/sh
for file in `grep -l '^Number: [23]' File*`
do
    ed -s $file <scr.ed
done

% chmod 755 scr.sh
% ./scr.sh
```

Comment: Is this a reply to another answer?

Comment: @RalfFriedl  Did I write something impertinently? The question was "replace string in multiple files" and that's exactly what my solution is doing. Sed does not replace the string in the file but in the stream.